# creating a star pattern using an elif statement and for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, shapes

I need to create the shape below using both a 'for loop' & 'elif statement' for an assignment.

I already have the code to create the shape using 'for loops'  only but I'm struggling to change it into a elif statement.

I'm only in my 3rd week of coding so not sure wether this code is concise legible code as I have been piecing it together from various websites all day. I also don't understand why I need to add an elif statement as its seems to complicate the process more?

```
rows = 6
for i in range(0, rows):
    for j in range(0, i + 1):
        print("*", end=' ')
    print(" ")


for i in range(rows + 1, 0, -1):
    for j in range(0, i - 1):
        print("*", end=' ')
    print(" ")
```

star pattern this code produces:

```
*

**

***

****

*****

******

******

*****

****

***

**

*
```

Comment: instead of two loops (one for the increasing of stars and one for the decreasing) make a single loop that iterates 2*nrows times and put a conditional inside to know if you are in a increasing phase or decreasing phase.

Comment: I don't really see a problem with using two loops if you feel it makes your solution easier to write and understand. That said, you probably would want to add comments indicating what each block of code did

Comment: Did you know that in python you can do this? `print("* " * 6)` :-)

Comment: It's unclear what you want the output to look like

Answer (score 0):

There is a mantra in programming "Do Not Repeat Yourself" aka "DRY". If you look at your current code, both looping blocks look like they do much of the same thing. It might not be a big deal here to duplicate the blocks and make the second one subtly different and honestly when rapidly prototyping I do that kind of thing all the time.

I will then typically go back and refactor/clean up the code to "DRY" it out. Again here it is no big thing, but imagine if the single `print("*", end=' ')` in the inner most loops was actually a more complicated set of code and that someone asked for a change. Now you (or the next person) needs to remember that this block of code was repeated.

Of course one way to solve that might be to replace whatever was in the inner loops with a call to a method and thus making the code a little more "DRY". The other way and perhaps what has been suggested to you is that one set of loops might be used to draw both ascending lines and descending lines.

Lets try that using @sembei-norimaki's recommendation.

```py
row_count = 6
start = 1
end = (2 * row_count) + 1
for row_number in range(start, end):
    star_count = row_number if row_number <= row_count else end - row_number
    for i in range(star_count):
        print("*", end=" ")
    print()
```

Note here we are calculating the number of stars to print based on a condition. If our `row_number` is less than or equal to the `row_count` then we are going to print a number of stars equal to the `row_number`. On the other hand once our `row_number` exceeds our `row_count` we will start reducing the number of starts to print.

This produces:

```
* 
* * 
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
* * * * * *
* * * * * *
* * * * *
* * * *
* * *
* *
*
```

The code here:

```py
    star_count = row_number if row_number <= row_count else end -
```

is your potential `if/else` block and is essentially the same as a more traditional:

```py
if row_number <= row_count:
    star_count = row_number
else:
    star_count = end - row_number
```

As a final simplification, if you multiply a string in Python you get a repeated string. Thus:

```py
print("* " * 2 == "* * ")
```

Should give you:

```
True
```

Using this we can do away with the inner loop and the extra call to `print()`

```py
row_count = 6
start = 1
end = (2 * row_count) + 1
for row_number in range(start, end):
    star_count = row_number if row_number <= row_count else end - row_number
    print("* " * star_count)
```

Comment: Thank you @JonSG! This really helped simplify a task that had stumped me and your explanation allowed me to understand very easily.